# React Native (intermediate value) (intermediate value) .bind is not a funciton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Can you tell why I'm getting this error? I'm trying to have a date countdown in React Native but I can't get the countdown to update in state. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
componentDidMount(){


    var end = new Date(theDate);
    console.log("end " + end);
    var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    console.log("End is: " + end);
    console.log("Now is: " + now);
    var distance = end - now;

    console.log("Distance is: " + distance)

     if (distance < 0) {

              clearInterval(timer);
             console.log('EXPIRED!');
      }

    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);

    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    this.setState({
        days: days,
        hours: hours,
        minutes: minutes,
        seconds: seconds
    }.bind(this));

    console.log("Remaining: " + days + ' days ' + hours + 'hrs '+ minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + ' secs')
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one place where you call `.bind`:

```
this.setState({
    days: days,
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
}.bind(this));
```

Objects don't have a `.bind` method, [only functions do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Not sure what you are trying to achieve here with `.bind`. Just remove it.